# why is domexception error is thrown when the code is not changed at all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having this error in developer environment when production works perfectly fine.. When the code is same as I have downloaded from version control. I am quite confused why this error is thrown .."DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded."?

Comment: is there any query parameter in the prod url which is missing in the dev url ?

Comment: You're trying to use atob to decode something that isn't valid base 64

Comment: yeah right..... I deleted the code which is decoding it worked after that............ thanks anyway..........